# New to java GUI and i have questions

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

Im making a bot for my friend who is on twitch, and he forgets to switch from his "brb" scene to his "game" scene on xsplit, so he wanted to make something where the mods could change or control somethings on his computer if he forgot.  it was easy making a bot for that.

The code was easy to make and it is like this.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class Twitchbot extends PircBot {

    public Twitchbot() {
        this.setName("Rex__Bot");
    }


    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {

        if(message.equals("Something")) {
            try {
                Robot r = new Robot();
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Something);
                r.delay(300);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_Something);

            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

   }
}
```

And i was wondering if there was a way to make a GUI to change the Letter that the message equals to and the keyevent.VK_Something to something different with the GUI so it would be easy for him to edit it.

Comment: You mean something like load the values from a configuration file?

Comment: Im not sure but ill look into configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to start with, you need some way to capture the information you want.  Basically, you need the message and the keystroke.  The keystroke consists of the virtual key and the modifiers.

The following example basically provides a means by which the user can type a message text and a key stroke.  The capture pane uses a `KeyListener` to monitor for key events and by extracting various values from the key event, it will then store the information it needs and displays the key character to the user.

You can the save this information to a `Properties` file which you can later load...

[image: KeyStroke]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test ();
    }

    public Test () {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ConfigurationPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ConfigurationPane extends JPanel {

        private KeyPressPane keyPressPane;
        private JTextField name;

        public ConfigurationPane() {

            name = new JTextField(10);
            keyPressPane = new KeyPressPane();

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(name, gbc);
            add(keyPressPane, gbc);

            JButton save = new JButton("Save");
            save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Properties p = new Properties();
                    p.setProperty("name", name.getText());
                    p.setProperty("keyCode", Integer.toString(keyPressPane.getKeyCode()));
                    p.setProperty("modifiers", Integer.toString(keyPressPane.getModifiers()));

                    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("Config.cfg"))) {
                        p.store(os, "Key config");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            add(save);

        }

    }

    public static class KeyPressPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final Border FOCUSED_BORDER = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
        protected static final Border UNFOCUSED_BORDER = UIManager.getBorder("TextField.border");

        private JLabel label;

        private int keyCode;
        private int modifiers;
        private char key;

        public KeyPressPane() {

            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel(" ");
            label.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(48f));
            add(label);
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                    modifiers = e.getModifiers();
                }

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                    char key = e.getKeyChar();
                    label.setText(Character.toString(key));
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    requestFocusInWindow();
                }
            });
            addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    setBorder(FOCUSED_BORDER);
                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("unfocused");
                    setBorder(UNFOCUSED_BORDER);
                }
            });
            setBorder(UNFOCUSED_BORDER);
            setFocusable(true);
        }

        public int getKeyCode() {
            return keyCode;
        }

        public int getModifiers() {
            return modifiers;
        }

    }

}
```

You then need to load the `Properties` file and create a new `KeyStroke`...

```
Properties p = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("Config.cfg"))) {
    p.load(is);

    String name = p.getProperty("name");
    int keyCode = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("keyCode"));
    int modifiers = Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("modifiers"));

    KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifiers);
    System.out.println(ks);

} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: alright thanks man, this helps, ill let you know the end result!

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i was wondering if you could help me implement it into my code, or if there is a good tutorial on how to use configuration files?

Comment: [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) and [Properties Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for the basics.  If you really want to be scared, [Introduction to JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)